# QHttp in not available in Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qnetworkaccessmanager, qhttp

I noticed that the `QHttp` class is no longer available in Qt5 and I keep getting an error message which says that I need to use the `QNetworkAccessManager` to do this.

Is there a way to access this class in Qt5?

Comment: Yes you need to either use QNetworkAccessManager (preferred) or use the compatibility add-on QtHttp which provides the QHttp class as it was in Qt4.

Comment: Thanks but what I don't understand is "how to do it". Am just a learner.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. You need to try to code something and then submit the code in order to get help here.

Comment: Ok but if I wanted to use the compatibility add-on QtHttp which provides the QHttp class as it was in Qt4. Is it like an included header file or is it added to the user.pro file.

Comment: Check [this](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/24466) topic. It explains how to install the compatibility add-on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple HTTP post (I am using Qt 5.3.2)

```
int Connection::postRequest(QString requestType, QUrl params){
    QString params_array = params.query();

    QNetworkRequest request(user->url);
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentLengthHeader, QByteArray::number(params_array.size()));
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    QEventLoop waitLoop;
    QNetworkAccessManager* connection = new QNetworkAccessManager(/*`this` can also be passed*/);
    QNetworkReply* reply = connection->post(request, params_array.toUtf8());
    QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &waitLoop, SLOT(quit()));
    waitLoop.exec();

    int errorCode = reply->error();
    if (errorCode != 0){
        // Show Error Message
    }
    else{
        // Parse "reply"
    }

    delete reply;
    delete connection;
    return errorCode;
}
```

Comment: Could you post your waitloop as well?

Answer (score 6):

Use `QNetworkAccessManager` in Qt 5. You can use an event loop to wait until the reply is finished and then read the available bytes :

```
QString My_class::My_Method()
{

   QNetworkAccessManager manager;

   QNetworkReply *reply = manager.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(myURL)));

   QEventLoop loop;
   connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
   connect(reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
   loop.exec();

   QByteArray bts = reply->readAll();
   QString str(bts);

   delete reply;

   return str;

}
```

You can also do it in an asynchronous way by connecting the `finished` signal of the `QNetworkAccessManager` to a slot :

```
connect(&manager,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(onFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
```

And read data there :

```
void onFinished(QNetworkReply* reply)
{

   if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
   {
       QByteArray bts = reply->readAll();

       ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you don't need to maintain a huge code base, the right way is to use new [QNetworkAccessManager](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) class instead.